# Linear, right fading to transparent gradient with additional fade at bottom

Tags: css, linear-gradients

The first time I couldn't create a good looking gradient with CSS3. There should be on the right side a fading to transparent gradient from black to transparent. At the bottom is the footer, so it needs to fade additionally at the bottom to transparent too.

An example how it may look like if possible:

[image]

The background of the page is an image, so no non-transparent fades are possible and please note that the page could be resized, so the position values and size values needs to be relative and no absolute pixel values.

Please provide just solutions with CSS gradients, no (background) images.

I tried already some possibilities, but no one looks really good:

```
div {
    position: relative;
    width: 500px;
    height: 300px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    background: url(http://www.okilla.com/uploadfile/1/2013/06/15/11371284566/1371286115_dark-noise-background-8.png);
    background-size: cover;
}

div:before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 80px;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(55deg, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 0%, 
                                            rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) 60%, 
                                            rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 100%), 
                -moz-linear-gradient(left, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 0%, 
                                           rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 40%, 
                                           rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 100%);
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(55deg, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 0%, 
                                               rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) 60%, 
                                               rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 100%), 
                -webkit-linear-gradient(left, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 0%, 
                                              rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 40%, 
                                              rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 100%);
    background-size: 100% 10%, 100% 90%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: bottom left, 0 1px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/RgYe2/

Comment: This is a great tool: http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/

Comment: Two times you could guess how I made the gradients ;) That tool isn't really useful in my case since it supports just one gradient per background.

Answer (score 0):

One idea would be the following: 2 linear gradients, and then a radial gradient to do the corner

```
#test {
    width: 800px;
    height: 400px;
    background-image: linear-gradient(90deg,black 60%, transparent 100%), linear-gradient(180deg, black, transparent), radial-gradient(ellipse at top left, black 1%, transparent 70%);
    background-size: 100% 80%, 60% 20%, 40% 20%;
    background-position: top left, bottom left, bottom right;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

body, html {
    height: 99%;
        background-color: lightblue;
}
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4Z5nj/)

Answer (score -1):

There is a very good website that generate gradient backgrounds, i use it on most of my projects. [Link here.](http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/)